# What does timeout operator measure exactly for a Mono chain in Reactor and Webflux?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

i'm using Spring Webflux and trying to understand the timeout concept for a chain of Monos.

For example, there's a chain of Mono calls:

```
myService.firstOperation()
.then(myService.secondOperation())
...
.then(myService.nOperation())
.timeout(3000L)
```

How is timeout going to be applied:

1) For the operations in general (sum time of operations)

2) For ech operation (each operation should take no longer than timeout)

3) Only for the last operation (nOperation)

?

I'm almost sure that timeout is applied to the last publisher. If so, how can timeout be applied to to the sum of operations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timeout operator measures the elapsed time between the time of subscription and the onNext/onComplete signal observed by the timeout operator.

Consider the following example:

```java
Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
    .then(Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
    .then(Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
    .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(2500))
    .block();
```

If statement 2 (time measured between operations) or 3 (only the duration of last operation counts) were correct, then the above piece of code wouldn't throw any error.

However, the case is that timeout operation measures the duration of everything upstream which makes **statement 1 (sum of all operations measured) CORRECT**.

In the example the sum of all operation (1000 + 1000 + 1000 = 3000ms) is bigger than the configured timeout (2500ms), thus the code results in an error.

Comment: public void test(){
        Mono.fromRunnable(() -> run(1))
                .then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> run(2)))
                .then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> run(3)))
        .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(1500)) //stage 2 will be executed, stage 3 - not
                .block();
    }

    private void run(int i){
        try {
            System.out.println("Running stage "+i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Running stage " +i +" done");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: you were right. Output is: Running stage 1 Running stage 1 done Running stage 2 Running stage 2 done.

Comment: For futher clarification: code sample above works with spring 2.4. Behaviour on spring 2.5 + is different

Comment: @Ermintar how is it different? I'm not aware of any change regarding this.

Comment: with project reactor 3.4.5+ timeout is still applied if sum of subprocesses times is greater than timeout duration.  However, all the processes in the chain are invoked, while in previous versions items in the chain after timeout were not executed. I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature. I've asked clarification question in github https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2933

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is pretty clear

> timeout - the timeout before the onNext signal from **this** Mono

So in you example the timeout is only applied to the Mono returned from the last `then`.

```
.then( ... )
.timeout(3000L)
```

the correct answer is:

*3) Only for the last operation (nOperation)*

Since this is last in the chain.

There is no timeout for the sum of operations, why would you need that?

Comment: Thanks, the idea is that a long process of N stages should terminate after timeout is reached. I could wrap it to a method and apply timeout to it, but in my case it looks dirty.