# Why are the timeout(Duration timeout) of both Mono/Flux fired based on accumulated time period

Tags: java, project-reactor

my case is showed as below:

I have two web requests named request1 and request2, the input of request2 comes from the output of request1. Now I want to set timeout for both of these two requests. Ideally, the time cost of request1 is 2s and the time cost of request2 is 3s. So I want to set the timeout of request1 as 3s and timeout of request2 as 4s. as the documentation of Mono#timeout said, I think it's possible to be done. But unfortunately the second timeout is calculated by accumulation. So I'm confused about the the meaning of **this mono**.

documentation of Mono#timeout(Duration timeout)(https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#timeout-java.time.Duration-)

```
public final Mono<T> timeout(Duration timeout)
Propagate a TimeoutException in case no item arrives within the given Duration.
Parameters:
timeout - the timeout before the onNext signal from this Mono
Returns: a Mono that can time out
```

sample code of my case:

```
Mono<String> startMono = Mono.just("start");
    String result = startMono
        .map(x -> {
          log.info("received message: {}", x);
          try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          }
          return "#1 enriched: " + x;
        })
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
          log.warn("Caught exception, apply fallback behavior #1", throwable);
          return Mono.just("item from backup #1");
        })
        .map(y -> {
          log.info("received message: {}", y);
          try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          }
          return "#2 enriched: " + y;
        })
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(4))
        // there is no timeoutException thrown if I set the second timeout to 6s (6s > 2s + 3s)
//        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(6))
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
          log.warn("Caught exception, apply fallback behavior #2", throwable);
          return Mono.just("item from backup #2");
        })
        .block();
    log.info("result: {}", result);
```

exception thrown from the above code:

```
16:46:51.080 [main] INFO  MonoDemo - received message: start
16:46:53.095 [elastic-2] INFO  MonoDemo - received message: #1 enriched: start
16:46:55.079 [parallel-1] WARN  MonoDemo - Caught exception, apply fallback behavior #2
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 4000ms in 'flatMap' (and no fallback has been configured)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:288) [reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.doTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:273) [reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutTimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:395) [reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onNext(StrictSubscriber.java:89) [reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) [reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:117) [reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) [reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) [reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
16:46:55.095 [main] INFO  MonoDemo - result: item from backup #2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timeout` operator measures the time from the subscription until the arrival of the first signal. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086824/6051176).

If you'd like to apply the timeout on the second operation only then you need to put `timeout` operator in a place where only the second request is in scope. See the following:

```java
public void execute() {
    firstRequest()
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> secondRequest())
        .onErrorReturn("some static fallback value if second failed as well")
        .block();
}

private Mono<String> firstRequest() {
    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .thenReturn("first")
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
        // additional mapping can be done here related to first request
}

private Mono<String> secondRequest() {
    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
        .thenReturn("second")
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(4));
        // additional mapping can be done here related to second request
}
```

By moving the `timeout` operator inside the private methods we ensure that only the duration of the those particular `Mono`s are measured and not the whole chain.

Comment: hi Martin. Thanks for your answer. I can get your point from your answer. but the most preferred answer of mine is the whole flow of the sample code. for example: where did the onNext signal come from and how did it transform through the whole flow and when was it processed and removed from the sequence ?

Comment: @AlvinYueChao I made some changes to make it resemble more to your code sample.