# What does timeout operator measure in Reactor and why it doesn't work in some cases?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

Recently, a reactive piece of code results in `timeout`, it involves redis operation, like this:

```
redisOps.entries(key).map(...).map(...).switchIfEmpty().timeout();
```

In order to identify if timeout happens in redis query, I think `timeout` should be located after `entries`, in this way, `map` consumed time would not be monitored by `timeout`. So I made a guess, and wrote demo.

1. does timeout monitor data emission elapsed time until it, and data operations after it is not counted? For example, in the following code snippet, only time consumption in `a` and `b` are monitored by `timeout`, not including `c` or `d`.

```
   Mono mono = foo();
   mono.a().b().timeout().c().d();
```

2. Why in the following code, `timeout` does not work.

```
           Mono.just("good luck")
                .map(s -> {
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return "timeout 1";
                })
                .map(s->{
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return "timeout 2";
                })
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

3. compared with item 2, `timeout` in the following code works:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            log.info("begin 1");
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            log.info("return 1");
            return "good luck 1";
        })
        .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(1500l))
        .map((s) -> {
            log.info("begin 2");
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            log.info("return 2");
            return "good luck 2";
        })
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: read the api https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#timeout-java.time.Duration- it it says `the timeout before the onNext signal from this Mono` Timeout returns a new Mono that can timeout. So it does not check everything before or anything after. What it does is that it takes the Mono returned from the single operator before, in your example `map` and then returns a new Mono that can timout.

Comment: @Toerktumlare *return a new Mono that can timeout* I am totally confused what is timeout. And the doc statement you refered confuses me too.

Comment: 1: timeout is measured between subscription and first observed onNext, onComplete signal from the timeout operator, see this example for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086824/6051176 2-3: this behaviour is due to thread sleep blocking main thread, see this github issue for details and workaround: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2350

Comment: As you are using reactive Redis library, you don't need to worry about this edge case. It'll work as you originally expected it.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Thanks, now things are clear. Reactor sometimes does not work as I expected, as recently I noticed `swtichIfEmpty(defaultData())` would run `defaultData` everytime, even if it is not empty (Intuitively, `defaultData` doesn't need to execute if data is not empty)

Answer (score 0):

Anwser the comment's question, some operator is `eager`, it will execute at assembly stage. you can use some `lazy` operator, eg: `defer`、`fromSupplier`...

```java
public Mono<?> defaultData() {
   return Mono.defer(() -> {
         //do Something
         return ...
   });
}
```

Here are some demo(https://github.com/echooymxq/reactive-study).